# How to pick multiple dates from jquery datepicker to multiple select box

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

> I have to pick mulitple dates from single date picker into multiple select box.
>    And also i have to remove selected date from multiple select box when remove button is clicked.
>
> There are so many plugins but i have to use jquery ui datepicker.
>
> As example I have something like this

[image: i have edited this in jsfiddle.]

Comment: i tried `altfield` but it applies only on `input`. when i try to use input then it displays date but then i select another date then it replace the old selected date. I have to use some logic that displays the selected dates into multiple select box and also removes the date from select box on remove button click.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **multidatespicker** http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/ which allows you to pick multiple dates.

that solves your problem of selecting multiple dates using one datepicker although i am not sure about the insertion of date in multiselect field. will update the answer as soon as i get it done.